# Unable to print output in specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I am not very good in designing but with some help I am able to acheive this code

My main issue is that when a user opens a div it becomes the target div, so if I have five divs open at the same time it doesn't matter which I type in because the text gets appended to the last opened div. I can also open an unlimited amount of the same div, which should not happen.

The small issue I have is that I'm unable to close the div and minimize it(much like fb when we click on the chat box it gets minimized).
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact">
    <header>Users</header>
    <main>
        <ul>
            <li id="Prashant"><a href="#">Prashant</a></li>
            <li id="Katrina"><a href="#">Katrina</a></li>
            <li id="Priyanka"><a href="#">Priyanka</a></li>
            <li id="Kareena"><a href="#">Kareena</a></li>
            <li id="Anushka"><a href="#">Anushka</a></li>
        </ul>
    </main>
</div>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
#contact {
    height: auto;
    background: #ececec;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100px;
}
#contact header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
}
#contact main {
    padding: 10px
}
#chat {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
#chat .user {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.user header {
    position: relative;
    background: #4b67a8;
    border: 1px solid #2e4588;
}
.user header .status {
    position: absolute;
    top: 36%;
    left: 10px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: green;
}
.user header .header-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
.user header .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 7px;
    color: #fff;
}
.message-area {
    background: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.user .input-area {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 3px;
}
.user .input-area input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var username = 'user201';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetUser = ($(this).html());
        $(document).data('chat.targetUser', targetUser);
        var user = '<div class="user open" id="' + targetUser + '"><header><div class="status"></div><div class="header-text">' + targetUser + '</div><div class="close">&times;</div></header><div class="message-area"></div><div class="input-area"><input type="text" id="input" /></div></div>';
        $('#chat').append(user);
    });

    $('#chat').on('keydown', '#input', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var targetUser = $(document).data('chat.targetUser');
            var txt = $(this).val();
            $('#' + targetUser + ' .message-area').append(username + ': ' + txt + '<br/>');
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would separate the UI from logic, which will help you track which users have an active chat window an deliver the messages properly, without requiring all of that global-data hackery.

Comment: @MasterAM i problem is resolved by the answer below still trying to resolve other problems

Comment: It is easy to put out fires at first when the code is small, but good design (in the sense of program architecture) is key to scaling and successfully handling greater complexity.

Comment: @MAsterAm totall agree with you but sometimes we have to take risks

Answer (score 4):

I edited div.close and added a div.mini like

```
<div class="mini" title="MINIMIZE">-</div>
<div class="close" title="CLOSE">&times;</div>
```

Css for .mini

```
.user header .mini { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS code for them to work

```
$(document).on("click", "div.close", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$(document).on("click", "div.mini", function(){
  var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children().not("header");
  elem.slideToggle();
});
```

Also added this js code to prevent add the div if it's already opened and make it append to last section of chat

```
if ($("div#" + targetUser).length > 0) {
   $("div#" + targetUser).appendTo("#chat");
   return false;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/20/)

**EDIT**

Edited div.mini click function for -/+ Minimize/Maximize

```
$(document).on("click", "div.mini", function(){
  var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children().not("header");
  elem.slideToggle();
  $(this).text($(this).text() == "-" ? "+" : "-");
  $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("title") == "MINIMIZE" ? "MAXIMIZE" : "MINIMIZE");   
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/21/)

Comment: @Batu just one last help if you could place a separate button for maximize actually I am not very good in JQuery

Comment: @Batu i wanted to slide down toggle not slideup toggle so that every div gets slide down separetly here all are sliding up. I tried this `elem.slideDown();` but it didn't work

Comment: Also if all divs are minimized and i maximize one div the position of all minimized div changes.

Answer (score 1):

The text you enter will appear in the last opened `div` because your `var targetUser` is changed every time you click on one of the users. The best way to solve this I think is to find the parent of the `input` field and search for the previous `.message-area`.

Like this:

```
$('#chat').on('keydown', '#input', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().prev(".message-area").append(username + ': ' + txt + '<br/>');
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/10/)

Comment: Ok that worked could you plz also tell me how to minimize and close the div.

Comment: I suggest you try it the same way with the text in the right `div`. If `.close` is clicked, find the next `.message-area` and `.input-area` and hide them.

Comment: Like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/19/). Please mark the answer that solved your question.

Comment: I changed the `.close` from a `div` to a `a` because it should be a link.

Comment: No it is not getting close and also it is not getting maximize after clicking again.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle, it closes when you click the `x`. Minimize and maximize will be the same method of finding the next/previous element and show/hide. I think you can manage that yourself.

Comment: That's fine but we are here to help. Not to write your code.

Comment: Sorry bro I am also asking for help I am deeply sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/36pcu/14/

I have updated the code in your fiddle, and I have added a fix so that the divs don't open up twice.

I just added a class to the link of the user, to show that this user is now active. Here is the code

```
if($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {

var targetUser = ($(this).html());
$(document).data('chat.targetUser', targetUser);
var user = '<div class="user open" id="' + targetUser + '"><header><div class="status"></div><div class="header-text">' + targetUser + '</div><div class="close">&times;</div></header><div class="message-area"></div><div class="input-area"><input type="text" id="input" /></div></div>';
$('#chat').append(user);
}
$(this).attr('class', 'active');
```

Then the div thing was handled using this code:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().prev(".message-area").append(username + ': ' + txt + '<br/>');
    $(this).val('');
}
```

This was the fix for your code, now it works.

Comment: @Afzal could you plz help me to close the div or minimize it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your statement "...Also I am able to open an unlimited amount of the same divs, which should not happen**..." this can be prevented if you know what are the boxes opened

please check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fsgc/17/)

```
var id = '#Box' + targetUser;
var existent = $('#chat').find(id)[0];
// This will ensure that you can only open one box at each time     
if(existent != null){
     alert('There is already one chat to user "' + targetUser + '" open');
}
else
{
     your code...
}
```

Also the fix proposed by speetje33 helps you prevent to write always in the last box.
I've added some comments to the code for your better understanding.

Comment: Actually this code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/36pcu/20/ but the only problem is when i maximize or minimize a div the position of all others divs get affected.If you can help to improve this code i will be more than grateful.

Comment: Indeed the code works fine, I made some adjustments to the CSS code in order to maintain the independence of the user boxes. Check the adjustments in the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/u56UH/5/